# Using methods to have a clear code

Tags: java, modularity

In java, I have a very long method. I want to break it down into multiple methods. Each method would be called only once.

I'm breaking the code into multiple methods to make it more clear. 
Is this a good reason ?

Comment: I should think so. Breaking a large code block into smaller chunks improves readability and increases maintainability of the code and makes debugging easier as well.

Comment: Yes, it's generally considered good practice to break down long methods for readability.

Comment: weird question from a user with such reputation & experience in software  development...

Comment: No it's not weird. This was a debate with someone who had several years of experience. besides, the code was inside a unit test. so testability was not a concern. the only concern was to make it readable. as none of the methods was supposed to be called more than once.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely!

Breaking a code into multiple methods can make your code more readable (Assuming the method names are clear and relevant to the method's output/functionality). In addition to the better description of the logic it helps with reusability in the future as well as writing test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is actually a very very common refactoring pattern called **[Extract method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html)**. Here is a neat little article on it ([link](http://alvinalexander.com/java/refactoring-extract-method-java-example)).